# Extract strings between brackets for each line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Suppose I have a text like this:

```
a b [c] d [e]
f [g]
[h]
i j
k [l]
```

I'd like to ask how to extract the strings between brackets line by line using sed or awk command?

The output should be:

```
c e
g
h

l
```

Edit: the following script seems to work.

```
while read -r line; do
  echo "$line" | awk 'NR > 1 {printf "%s ", $1;}' RS='[' FS=']';
  echo ; 
done < file.txt;
```

Comment: It is always recommended to add your efforts too in your post which you have put in order to fix your problem. Kindly do so.

Comment: I've updated a working concise awk script. Please reopen it.

Comment: I have voted to reopen now. Other 2 votes required too.

Comment: @jwenting Please check whether to open it.

Comment: @Thomas Ayoub Please check whether to open it.

Comment: Could you help contact the other two to check my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[^[]*(\[([^]]*)\])*( *)[^[]*/\2\3/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/\[[^\]]*/)){
    val=(val?val OFS substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH):substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH))
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
{
  gsub(/\[|\]/,"",val)
  print val
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** With simple `for` loop solution.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^\[.*\]/){
      gsub(/\]|\[/,"",$i)
      printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?"":OFS)
    }
  }
  print ""
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
c e
g
h

l
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk, `FS="[][]"` and the observation that every even numbered field needs to be printed:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS="[][]" }
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)   # get every other field separated by [ and ]
        b=b $i OFS        # buffer them up, there will be a trailing OFS
    print b; b=""         # output
}' file
```

Output:

```
c e 
g 
h 

l
```

Solution expects that there are no unpaired or nested `[]`s

Answer (score 0):

Another GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='[][]' -F'\n' 'NR>1{printf("%s",((NR+1)%2?$0:" "));for(i=1;i<NF;i++){printf "\n"}}' file
```

The record separator `RS` is set to `[` or `]`. That allows to capture records in between these square braces with the number record `NR` and `NR+1%2`.

The `-F` and the `for` statement prints the newline according to the input file.